# Disable specific dates jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, wordpress, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I tried this:

```
var disabledDays = ["2017-03-16","2017-03-20","2017-03-29","1717-0404-0303"];

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var unavailableDates = ["2017-03-16","2017-03-13","2017-03-21"];

  function unavailable(date) {
    // dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    dmy = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
      return [true,"","Book Now"];
    } else {
      return [false,"","Booked Out"];
    }
  }

  jQuery('#checkin').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    constrainInput: true,        
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
  }).on('change', function() { 
    jQuery(this).valid(); 
  });  
});
```

I just can't figure out why it keep saying:

> Cannot read property 'inArray' of undefined

I tried like 100 codes same like this, by god same error. and all those codes are working fine in their demo.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Does the `$` variable point to jQuery? Everywhere else in your code you use `jQuery`, which implies you've called `$.noConflict()` somewhere

Comment: Great!!.. Me dumb... can you please tell me how to get month like"03" not"3" ?

Comment: Sure, I added an answer covering both issues for you

Answer (score 0):

The error would imply that the `$` variable is not pointing to jQuery. This is also backed up by the fact you're using `jQuery` in all other points in your code. To fix this you can either change `$.inArray()` to `jQuery.inArray()` throughout your code, or better yet you can alias the instance of jQuery that's passed in to the document.ready handler.

From there you have an issue with your date format as your array includes leading zeroes on the month and day values, yet the `dmy` variable does not. To fix this you could use the `toISOString()` method of the date and remove the time from it. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) { // < note the $ alias here
    var unavailableDates = ["2017-03-16", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-21"];

    function unavailable(date) {
        var dmy = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
            return [true, "", "Book Now"];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Booked Out"];
        }
    }

    $('#checkin').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        constrainInput: true,
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        beforeShowDay: unavailable
    }).on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid();
    });
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/sLns93zp/)

Comment: But it is disabling next date.. Like instead of 16.. its disabling 17

Comment: That's most likely caused by timezone offsets. You can force leading zeroes on the values by adding `"00"` to the start of the string and calling `.slice(-2)`, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sLns93zp/1/